# CakePHP ACL tutorial group_id

Tags: php, cakephp

I am following the 
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html tutorial and I am at the part where you add the group and user accounts...

However, when I access to add new user, the drop down for the group is is empty... What can be wrong?

here is how User.php model looks like

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Group $Group
 * @property Image $Image
 */
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function beforeSave() {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['password']);
        return true;
    }   
    public function bindNode($user) {
            return array('model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['User']['group_id']);
    }   

    public function parentNode() {
        if (!$this->id && empty($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }   
        if (isset($this->data['User']['group_id'])) {
            $groupId = $this->data['User']['group_id'];
        } else {
            $groupId = $this->field('group_id');

       }
        if (!$groupId) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return array('Group' => array('id' => $groupId));
        }
    }
      public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '', 
            'fields' => '', 
            'order' => ''
            )   
        );  



    public $hasMany = array(
            'Image' => array(
                'className' => 'Image',
                'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                'dependent' => false,
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => '',
                'limit' => '',
                'offset' => '',
                'exclusive' => '',
                'finderQuery' => '',
                'counterQuery' => ''
                )
            );

}
```

Here is how Group.php model looks like

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Group Model
 *
 * @property User $User
 */
class Group extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'name';
/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
        //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $actsAs = array('Acl' => array('type' => 'requester'));

    public function parentNode() {
        return null;
    }   
    public $hasMany = array(
            'User' => array(
                'className' => 'User',
                'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
           'dependent' => false,
                'conditions' => '',
                'fields' => '',
                'order' => '',
                'limit' => '',
                'offset' => '',
                'exclusive' => '',
                'finderQuery' => '',
                'counterQuery' => ''
                )
            );

}
```

my tables look like this 
'users' table

```
>     > Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
>     > id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
>     > username    varchar(64) NO  UNI NULL      password  varchar(82) NO      NULL     
>     > first_name  varchar(64) NO      NULL      last_name varchar(64) NO      NULL     
>     > created datetime    YES     NULL      group_id  int(11) NO      NULL
```

'groups' table

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
name    varchar(100)    NO      NULL     
created datetime    YES     NULL     
modified    datetime    YES     NULL
```

View/Users/add.ctp code

```
<div class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add User'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
        echo $this->Form->input('group_id');
    ?>  
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit'));?>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <h3><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></h3>
    <ul>

        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), array('action' => 'index'));?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Groups'), array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Group'), array('controller' => 'groups', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('List Images'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Image'), array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'add')); ?> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I created 2 groups. One is "visitors" and one is "admin".. 
here is how `aros` table looks like right now now

```
id  parent_id   model   foreign_key alias   lft rght
        2   NULL    Group   4       1   2
        3   NULL    Group   5       3   4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added group first? First you have to add the group then try adding the user.

Please verify you have a belongsTo relationship setup in the user model `User.php`

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Group' => array(
        'className' => 'Group',
        'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Check your UserController Add method has the following code
Please verify the `$groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('groups'));` part

```
    public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('groups'));
}
```

Comment: Yes I have added the group first.

Comment: the field in the view looks like  echo $this->Form->input('group_id');

Comment: can you please post the User model. I think the relation you haven't set properly

Comment: @CodeCrack Updated the answer please verify that.

Comment: Yes I have that as well. I edited my original post with the User and Group model code.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it. How was I supposed to know that?! THat was not in the guide and bake doesn't generate stuff like that.

Comment: Bake should generate that code automatically if you have mentioned the relationship in the Model. I am not sure how it missed.

Comment: so $groups = $this->User->Group->find('list'); finds all the groups in the group table and $this->set(compact('groups')); sets group array to what? Not sure how it's all associated like that.

Comment: `$groups = $this->User->Group->find('list');` get all the group name with key as group_id.   `$this->set(compact('groups'));` will send this value to the view. So if you want to send any value from you controller to view you can use  `$this->set('variableName', $Variable);`

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. What about the relationship of $displayField = "name" in Group.php and group_id in the add.ctp? Don't really understand that variable well even after reading the docs.

Comment: `$displayField = "name"` used to display the values in the related view. eg: For the Groups Model you have mentioned `group_name` as the display field, So When you access the Groups in the Users model it will display the `group_name` in the list box. If you mention group_id instead of `group_name` as display field, `group_id` will be display in the select box.

Comment: Thanks dude! I am almost at the end of the tutorial but ran into another problem. Check it here please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379335/cakephp-acl-tutorial-initdb-function-warnings