# CakePHP ACL tutorial initDB function warnings

Tags: php, cakephp

I am following http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html tutorial and I got a bit slightly different groups (group 4 and 5) 4 is visitors and 5 is admins

```
    function initDB() {
 10         $group = $this->User->Group;
 11         //Allow admins to everything
 12         $group->id = 5;      
 13         $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');
 14        //^doesnt work
 15        //$this->Acl->allow(array( 'model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 5), 'controllers');
 16        
 17        
 18         $group->id = 4;
 19         $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
 20         $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/User/login');
 21         $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/User/logout');
 22        /*
 23        $this->Acl->deny(array( 'model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 4), 'controllers');
 24        $this->Acl->allow(array( 'model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 4), 'controllers/User/login');
 25        $this->Acl->allow(array( 'model' => 'Group', 'foreign_key' => 4), 'controllers/User/logout');
 26 */      
 27         
 28         
 29         echo "all done";
 30         exit();
 31     }
```

but when I run this function I get the following errors

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 387]
Warning (512): DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 387]all done
```

what gives?!

edit - my App Controller looks like this

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
            'Acl',
            'Auth' => array(
                'authorize' => array(
                    'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
                    )   
                ),  
            'Session'
            );  
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';
        //Configure AuthComponent
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->allow('display');
    }   
}


?>
```

EDIT 2:
Full Warning looks like this

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 387]
Code Context
DbAcl::allow() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 387
AclComponent::allow() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AclComponent.php, line 128
UsersController::initDB() - APP/Controller/UsersController.php, line 20
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 473
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 107
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 89
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 96
```

Let me know if you want me to post up any other code.

Comment: have you installed the `AclExtras` plugin and run the `./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync` command?

Comment: I have updated the code to my actual code.

Comment: have you tried to login and access the modules? is it working fine, as it is warnings just try whether it is working fine or not?

Comment: When I try to log in, it doesn't redirect and nothing happens. I still can access the Images (aka Posts) link but when I try to delete a post or upload a new image, it asks me to log in (like it should) but when I try to log in, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: have you verified the group_id you mentioned in the initDB method exist or not?

Comment: Yes group_id 4 is group visitor group_id 5 is group admin

Comment: I added the full warning.. check it out

Comment: can you please remove `$this->Auth->actionPath = 'controllers/';` this line from the beforeFilter method and try again.

Comment: I removed it. Still get the same warning running initDB and when I try to log in, it doesn't redirect me anywhere, just stays on that page. (I am guessing that's because initDB is giving me warnings). Any other code I should post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the warning, and to the fact you're calling 3 times `$this->Acl->allow()` and once `$this->Acl->deny()` but seem to get only 2 warnings, I assume that the lines that give a warning are the following:

```
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/User/login');
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/User/logout');
```

I don't use AclExtras to synchronize the acos table with the existing actions, but AFAIK when checking the permissions the AclComponent requires the controller aliases in the acos table to be pluralized. So I assume that your acos table doesn't contain any record with alias `User` but a record with alias `Users`.

This would explain why you don't have any node in your acos table that can be identified by `'controllers/User/login'` nor by `'controllers/User/logout'`.

If my assumptions are correct, the following code would work:

```
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Users/login');
$this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Users/logout');
```

Comment: You were right! Why would it use Users instead of User though?

Comment: These paths lead to actions in controllers. In Cake, the controller's names are made of the pluralized model name (`UsersController` for the model `User`). I guess it follows the same logic here. Thanks you for having accepted my answer by the way :-)